# ggplot2 vs sm package density plot output (and statistical analysis)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following data frame example

```
library('ggplot2')
library('sm')

    original<-c(1:100,1)
    a<-sample(original,100)
    b<-rep(1:4,25)
    lala<-data.frame(a,b)
```

My aim is to produce density plots for values in lala$a, according to each group (1,2,3,4) defined in lala$b.

For doing so in ggplot2 I could do the following

```
plotDensityggplot<-ggplot()+
  geom_density(data = lala, aes(a, colour=factor(b)))+
  theme_classic()
print(plotDensityggplot)
```

producing this:

[image]

However, when I plot the same data using the 'sm' package to make a formal comparison of the densities using the following code:

```
sm.density.compare(lala$a,as.numeric(lala$b),model = "equal")
```

The density curves extend beyond zero in the X-axis, despite there is no value below zero in lala$a

[image]

What's going on? - note that this affect the densities reported in the y-axis.

Is the p-value from the permutation test of equality obtained from sm.density.compare a reliable estimate? - thank you!

Comment: Don't know about the `sm` package, but you're pointing to a criticism that some have with density plots, which is that they overfit the data.

Comment: Try setting `xlim = range(lala$a)` in the `sm` plot.

Comment: Hi @Rui Barradas, If I do that the p-value changes from p<0.01 in my question to p=0 when modifying the axis.... does it mean the axis defines the points considered for comparison? - is this reliable?

Comment: I am surprised to that the p-values have changed, I thought it was just a graphical parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, you can (more or less) reproduce the `sm` output in `ggplot` by pre-computing densities with base R's `density` (I'm not familiar with `sm` but I imagine that `sm.density` calls base R's `density` at some point as well).

```
library(tidyverse)
lala %>%
    group_by(b) %>%
    summarise(tmp = list(map_dfc(c("x", "y"), ~density(a)[.x]))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, y, colour = as.factor(b))) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

I'm not sure how `geom_density` (or `stat_density`) tune kernel density estimation parameters, but you seem to have less control over them than in base R's `density`.

Comment: Hi Maurits. Thanks for your response. So what would that mean? - sm is providing the correct plot? Why does the ggplot version without pre-computing density show the highest density going above 0.015?.  I am a bit confused here. What is geom_density  reporting if not density?  is sm a fair approach to compare these densities?

Comment: @JPV Keep in mind that `density` performs a kernel density *estimation*, where certain parameters like the smoothing bandwidth can be estimated in different ways. As such, kernel density estimation is a statistical inference method that provides different results for different parameters. The question is what you are trying to do with these density estimates. Personally I would not use density estimates in a hypothesis test; instead model/test the data directly. If you want to compare two distributions, use a parametric or non-parametric test on the raw (i.e. non-density-smoothed) data.

Comment: that makes more sense. I am trying to compare the epidemic size (i.e. number of individuals infected) in 3 different models of infection. For each model I have run Z realisations, and therefore I can plot the epidemic size as a histogram that ranges from zero (no individual infected in any of the z realisation), to a number x (x individuals infected in y out of Z realizations of the model). I want to compare the epidemic size obtained in the 3 models of infection. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @JPV I'd first try to understand the underlying probability distribution of epidemic size. If it is (log-)normally distributed, I'd start by assessing differences in the mean epidemic size with e.g. an ANOVA on the (log-transformed) data of epidemic sizes for the 3 different models. Alternatively a non-parametric Kolmogorov-Smirnov test allows you to do pairwise-comparisons of the epidemic size empirical cumulative distribution across the 3 data sets. You'd have to do some form of post-hoc test to correct for multiple testing.